# perf intel_pt couldn't resolve symbols at .plt sections

Tags: linux, symbols, trace, processor, perf

I tried to leverage perf to record the exection flow of binary, as well as call stacks. For resolving the symbols, I installed all of the necessary debug packages (like `-dbg` and `dbgsym` packages).

Now it's feasible for perf to resolve symbols of the binary, however, those plt symbols could not be resolved. An example:

My commande:

```
perf record -e intel_pt//u wget www.google.com
perf script --itrace=cri0ns -F+flags,+insn,+ip,+pid,+tid,+sym
```

```
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:   jcc                      562233367dec xcalloc+0x1c (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 75 0f
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:   call                     562233367dee xcalloc+0x1e (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 7d ff fb ff
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1     branches:u:   call                     562233367dee xcalloc+0x1e (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 7d ff fb ff
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:                            562233327d70 [unknown] (/usr/bin/wget) insn: f3 0f 1e fa
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:   jmp                      562233327d74 [unknown] (/usr/bin/wget) insn: f2 ff 25 0d 50 07 00
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:                            7f73b9ec2c90 __libc_calloc+0x0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so) insn: f3 0f 1e fa
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:                            7f73b9ec2c94 __libc_calloc+0x4 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so) insn: 41 55
            wget 246443/246443 [006] 3733275.105775:          1 instructions:u:                            7f73b9ec2c96 __libc_calloc+0x6 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so) insn: 48 89 f8
```

As you could see, those `[unknown]` symbols represents the `.plt` section. But why then didn't be resolved?

Comment: Can you add the precise command line you used to record and report IntelPT traces?

Comment: Possible workaround: build with `gcc -fno-plt` to have it use `call *calloc@GOTPCREL(%rip)` instead of `call calloc@plt`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need dbgsym for wget itself or recompile it from source with `gcc -fno-plt` as suggested above. Tried it myself with [dbg package](http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/pool/main/w/wget/wget-dbgsym_1.20.1-1.1_amd64.deb) and my perf script output is like this.

````
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150ae0 ptimer_new+0x0 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 55
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150ae1 ptimer_new+0x1 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: bf 01 00 00 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150ae6 ptimer_new+0x6 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: be 20 00 00 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150aeb ptimer_new+0xb (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 53
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150aec ptimer_new+0xc (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 83 ec 28
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150af0 ptimer_new+0x10 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150af9 ptimer_new+0x19 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 89 44 24 18
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e2150afe ptimer_new+0x1e (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 31 c0
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:   call             55a0e2150b00 ptimer_new+0x20 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 7b 9e 01 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1     branches:u:   call             55a0e2150b00 ptimer_new+0x20 (/usr/bin/wget) =>     55a0e216a980 xcalloc+0x0 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 7b 9e 01 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a980 xcalloc+0x0 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 89 f8
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a983 xcalloc+0x3 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 83 ec 08
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a987 xcalloc+0x7 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 f7 e6
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a98a xcalloc+0xa (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 0f 90 c2
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a98d xcalloc+0xd (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 85 c0
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:   jcc              55a0e216a990 xcalloc+0x10 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 78 17
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a992 xcalloc+0x12 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 0f b6 d2
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    55a0e216a995 xcalloc+0x15 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 48 85 d2
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:   jcc              55a0e216a998 xcalloc+0x18 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: 75 0f
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:   call             55a0e216a99a xcalloc+0x1a (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 41 11 fc ff
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1     branches:u:   call             55a0e216a99a xcalloc+0x1a (/usr/bin/wget) =>     55a0e212bae0 calloc@plt+0x0 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: e8 41 11 fc ff
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:   jmp              55a0e212bae0 calloc@plt+0x0 (/usr/bin/wget) insn: ff 25 ea 32 06 00
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    7fb6f386e120 __libc_calloc+0x0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so) insn: 48 89 fa
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    7fb6f386e123 __libc_calloc+0x3 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so) insn: 41 56
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    7fb6f386e125 __libc_calloc+0x5 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so) insn: b8 ff ff ff ff
            wget 30246/30246 [029] 8799199.428350:          1 instructions:u:                    7fb6f386e12a __libc_calloc+0xa (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so) insn: 41 55```
````

Comment: Oh... Thanks! But I've already installed the wget's dbgsym, so that I need to recompile wget?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, maybe your env is not the same as mine. Though I guess wget is just an example. Are you trying so solve any real issue which is related to the unknown symbols in .plt section ?